# Selecting All the columns except IDENTITY Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, vbscript

I am trying to display **all the columns** available in the table **EXCEPT IDENTITY COLUMN**.
Is it possible?

Pseudo code would be something like this.

```
SELECT * FROM Tab1 WHERE IDENTIY = NULL
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM Tab1 WHERE IDENTIY <> 'YES'
```

This is obviously invalid. But I want to achieve something like this.
Is it possible??

PS. I am doing this through SQL server connection from VBScript, and I dont want to hard code the column names( Obviously for flexibility).

Here's the VbScript snippet.

```
SQL_Cols = "select Column_name from Information_schema.columns where Table_name = 'Tab1'"
Recordset.open SQL_Cols,ConnString
p = recordset.getrows()
STR_Cols = ""
for i=1 to Ubound(p,2)   ' from 1 to UBound since in p(0,0) name of identity column is stored   
    if i = Ubound(p,2) Then
        STR_Cols  = STR_Cols  &"["&p(0,i)&"]" 
    else
        STR_Cols  = STR_Cols  &"["&p(0,i)&"],"
    end if
NEXT
Recordset.close
```

**STR_Cols** stores all the column names (Except 1st one (which is an identity Column))

Which i am later using to perform the down streaming task. 
This is working absolutely fine only one thing. This would work only if the 1st column is IDENTIY column, if the table is altered, the code will have to be changed. I want the code to be as flexible and robust as possible.

Comment: Instead of using *, replace it with all the column names, except the one you want to exclude.

Comment: Generally `SELECT *` should never be used from code, your program should always name the columns it wants in-order; otherwise if the table is modified then the order (and possibly presence) of the columns would be different and your program might fail, crash, destroy the world.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try like this:

`sys.columns`=Contains All Columns regarding to Particular Database

`sys.tables`=Contains All Tables regarding to Particular Database

`sys.identity_columns`=Contains All identity Columns regarding to Particular Database

So Result Can be Generated By `joins` with `is_identity=1` and Exclude Identity column with `Not IN` with all columns to particular table

```
select c.name from sys.columns c
join sys.tables AS t
on t.object_id=c.object_id
where c.name not in (select name from sys.identity_columns where is_identity=1)
and  t.name='MyTableName'
```

Comment: This is cool! If i use this in my vbscript. **p=recordset.getrows** contains all the columns except  Identity column.

Comment: @Anantvaibhav Added some desc

Comment: So I believe  this would work fine even if the identity column is not the first column and maybe between certain other columns??

Comment: @Anantvaibhav Yes Ordering is not a concern when using `sys.identity_columns`

Answer (score 3):

Try this. Use `Sys.columns` table to get the column list without `identity column`. Then use `Dynamic SQL` to generate column list and execute the query

```
declare @ collist varchar(max)='',@ sql nvarchar(max)
select @collist += ','+name from sys.columns where object_name(object_id)='Tab1' and is_identity <> 1
select @collist = right(@collist,len(@collist)-1)
set @sql ='select '+@collist+ ' from Tab1'
exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: This working perfectly in SQL. I will try in my VBScript

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT * INTO #TempTable FROM YourTable

/* Drop the IDENTITY cloumn */
ALTER TABLE #TempTable DROP COLUMN ID_COLUMN

/* SELECT New result and drop temp table */
SELECT * FROM #TempTable 
DROP TABLE #TempTable
```

Comment: This can be used if u have large no of columns to be selected

Answer (score 0):

Don't Specify the column name which are not needed. instead of specifying * specify the column name that are needed.

```
SELECT Col1, Col3, Col6, Col8 FROM Tab1
```

Here `Col1, Col3, Col6, Col8 are selected and Col2, Col4, Col5 and Col7` are excluded from select query.

Answer (score 0):

You will get Identity columns by executing following query :

```
    SELECT
    clmns.name
    FROM
    sys.tables AS tbl
    INNER JOIN sys.all_columns AS clmns ON clmns.object_id=tbl.object_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.indexes AS ik ON ik.object_id = clmns.object_id and 1=ik.is_primary_key
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.index_columns AS cik ON cik.index_id = ik.index_id and cik.column_id = clmns.column_id and cik.object_id = clmns.object_id and 0 = cik.is_included_column
    where tbl.name = N'Tab1' AND is_identity = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a solution same as what Pradeep suggested :

```
SQL_Cols = "declare @collist varchar(max)=''; select @collist += ', ' + name from sys.columns where object_name(object_id) = 'Tab1' and is_identity <> 1; select @collist = right(@collist,(case when len(@collist) > 2 then len(@collist)-2 else @collist end)); select @collist as [ColumnNames];"
Recordset.open SQL_Cols,ConnString
p = recordset.getrows()
STR_Cols = p(0,0)
```

check value of `STR_Cols`

Comment: **p = recordset.getrows()** pops an error: " Operation not allowed when object is closed" and when I close the recordset it pops "Not allowed when object is open". Probably There's a prob with the connection of **SQL_Cols** querry. because other queries are working fine in same context.

Comment: Probably because of multiple **SELECT** Statements

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query: I found this one working properly. This will select data in columns without identity = 1

```
DECLARE @Temp NVARCHAR(MAX); 
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @Temp = '';
SELECT @Temp = @Temp + COLUMN_NAME + ', ' FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME ='Person' AND  columnProperty(object_id(TABLE_NAME), COLUMN_NAME, 'IsIdentity') != 1 

SET @SQL = 'SELECT ' + SUBSTRING(@Temp, 0, LEN(@Temp)) +' FROM [Person]';
EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL;
```

You can get the column name details from sys.columns table

Try the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM SYS.COLUMNS 
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.TableName') 
AND [Name] <> 'ColumnName'

DECLARE @sql as VARCHAR(8000)
SET @sql = 'SELECT '

SELECT @sql += [Name] + ', ' FROM SYS.COLUMNS 
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.TableName') 
AND [Name] <> 'ColumnName'

SELECT @sql += ' FROM Dbo.TableName'

EXEC(@sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26967566/1307183) by [@Dgan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2978469/dgan) will have issues if you use the same column name as an identity column on multiple tables. In order to restrict to just the table you are looking for, you need to also match the table's `object_id` in `sys.identity_columns`, like so:

```
SELECT c.[name], t.object_id
FROM sys.tables t
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
WHERE 1=1
  AND t.[name] = '<table_name>'
  AND c.[name] NOT IN (
    SELECT [name]
    FROM sys.identity_columns ic
    WHERE ic.is_identity = 1 AND ic.object_id = t.object_id
  )
```